# How can I get my apex domain to work with heroku and zerigo DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns, zerigo

After hours on this, I'm punting.

I have the domain example.com and I have the nameservers for it pointed at zerigo's recommended ones (anyone who has used zerigo on heroku will know about this:  a.ns.zerigo.net to e.ns.zerigo.net)

In the zerigo control panel, there are three A records for example.com that point to three different IPs.

I also have a CNAME record for *.example.com that points to example.herokuapp.com

That's it; a total of four records.

Right now the subdomains work fine; I can enter anything.example.com and it acts properly.

But the apex domain gives me this "Access to bamboo http endpoint denied" nonsense.  Which is really frustrating because when I ping example.com it pings successfully one of the three ips from the A records.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same error (but using DNSimple instead of Zerigo)

Comment: Aaron my comment was too long so I posted an answer below. hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I'm sure you are discovering, sometimes you might have it configured correctly but because you aren't sure whether the changes to DNS are propagating through, you get impatient and start tweaking stuff. I think that's what I did.

Anyway, the current configuration that works is this:

The A records are all gone.  Instead I have:

- a redirect record that redirects example.com to www.example.com
- a cname record that points *.example.com to example.herokuapp.com
- a cname record that points www.example.com to example.herokuapp.com

Those are the only records in the zerigo dns cpanel, and I suspect that a zerigo guy responded to my support ticket and set them up because I'm pretty sure I did not delete the A records.

It is worth mentioning, maybe, that the only domain I added to the heroku account was example.com  I did NOT add www.example.com or *.example.com via domain:add

Hope this helps!